# How do Taylor Series represent analytic functions when the function has a singularity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

So I'm reading Taylor's Theorem:

> Let $f(z)$ be analytic in a domain $D$, and let $z=z_0$ be any point in $D$. Then there exists precisely one Taylor series (1) with center $z_0$ that represents $f(z)$. This representation is valid in the largest open disk with center $z_0$ in which $f(z)$ is analytic.

And my book's text re: Taylor and Power series:

> We see that Taylor series are power series. From the last section we know that power series represent analytic functions. And we now show that every analytic function can be represented by power series, namely, by Taylor series (with various centers). This makes Taylor series very important in complex analysis. Indeed, they are more fundamental in complex analysis than their real counterparts are in calculus... They are the most important series in complex analysis because their sums are analytic functions (Theorem 5, Sec. 15.3), and every analytic function can be represented by power series

But the geometric series can be represented by this function:

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1 - z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n = 1 + z + z^2 + \dots$$ which converges if $\left | z \right | < 1$

$f(z)$ is singular at $z = 1$. Is it still analytic?

My definitions of analytic:

> A function $f(z)$ is said to be analytic in a region $R$ of the complex plane if $f(z)$ has a derivative at each point of $R$ and if $f(z)$ is single valued.

If the geometric function is undefined at $z = 1$, is it still analytic?

Comment: It is analytic on the open disc $|z|\lt1$.  Indeed it is analytic everywhere except at $z=1$.  For every $a\ne1$, it has a Taylor series centred at $z=a$, which is valid for $|z-a|\lt|1-a|$.  These regions overlap to cover every number except $z=1$.  It is not analytic on the whole plane $\mathbb C$

Comment: Can you expand what you mean by when you say: "for every $a \ne 1$, it has a taylor series centered at z = a..."

Comment: $1/(1-z)=\sum_k c_k(z-a)^k$, where the sequence of $c_k$ is a different sequence for each $a$

Comment: So if you can write Taylor series for functions that aren't analytic everywhere... what's the point of Laurent series?

Comment: The Laurent series at $1$ is just $-(z-1)^{-1}$, its 'annulus of convergence' is $|z-1|\in (0,\infty)$ quite different to the Taylor series at $a\ne 1$ that converges only for $|z-a|<|1-a|$

Comment: The Taylor series break down at 1, but the Laurent series tells you more precisely how big the function is near 1.  Also, if you  integrate the function on a loop around 1, the answer id $2\pi i$ times the coefficient of $(z-1)^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

One of the "magic" things about complex analysis is that
$$
f:U\to\mathbb{C} \text{ is (complex) differentiable at } z_0\in U
$$
is equivalent to
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n \text{ in some neighborhood of } z_0
$$
(where $a_n=f^{(n)}(z_0)/n!$ as they have to be).

Now, $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$ is differentiable on its domain $U=\mathbb{C}\backslash\{1\}$, so at every $z_0\in U$, $f$ can be written as a power series (which will have radius of convergence $R=|z_0-1|$, the distance to the nearest/only singularity).  Namely
$$
\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1}{1-z_0-(z-z_0)}=\frac{1}{1-z_0}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z-z_0}{1-z_0}}=\frac{1}{1-z_0}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1-z_0)^n}(z-z_0)^n.
$$

Comment: Just a bit confused about the notation... how can teh function be differentiable at $z_0$ when it's not even defined at 1 which is $z_0$